# Target one specific piece of data and update its state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I have a piece of data and I store it in a state as follows:

```
interface DataType {[key: string]: string;}

const [data, setData] = React.useState<DataType>({
{
    "Widget1": "weather",
    "Widget2": "timer",
    "Widget3": "clock"
});
```

And I want a function to update a single widget, what would be the best way to do so. I tried using one function for each widget, but that is obviously not best practice.

```
const widget1Handler = (widget: string) => {
var updatedData = {
  Widget1: widget,
  Widget2: data.Widget2,
  Widget3: data.Widget3,
  Widget4: data.Widget4
};
setData(updatedData);
};
```

Same for `Widget2` and so on. Better would be one function for all of them something like this:

```
const widgetHandler = (widget: string, widgetNr: number ) => {
const updatedData = ???;
setData(updatedData);
}
```

How can I target one specific value and update its state?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically selected the property name by using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). This will allow you can pass in the widget number to `widgetHandler`, and update the state.

```
const widgetHandler = (widget: string, widgetNr: number ) => {
  // const someData = ???;
  setData({
    ...data,
    ['Widget' + widgetNr.toString()]: someData 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of state updater callback and pass in the widget number to the updater function like `widget2` and so on

```
const widgetHandler = (widget: string, widgetNr: number ) => {
   // widgetNr should be of the format Widget1, Widget2 and so on

    setData(previousData => ({
         ...previousData,   // spreading all the previous values
         [widgetNr]: widget // updating the required value
    }));
}
```